# Replace a string from a textarea with another text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea with code of form which the users would copy and paste into their  website.

The html in the textarea would be something like this

**UPDATE : Note the below form is enclosed in a textarea. This would a plain text in a textarea**

```
<form action="https://www.xxxxxxx.com/servlet/servlet?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

I want to change the url of the form tag to https://www.yyyyyyyyy.com/parse.php and copy the changed form code into another textarea using jquery or normal javascript. Below is the full html

```
<form>
 <textarea rows="10" cols="80" id="oldCode">
  <form action="https://www.xxxxxxx.com/servlet/servlet?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
</textarea>
    <button onclick="generateCode()">Generate new Code</button>
<textarea id="newCode" rows="10" cols="80">
</textarea>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in following way, put `type="button"` for button element as this submits forms everytime

```
<button type="button" id="generate" >Generate new Code</button>
```

use below jQuery where bind click event to button and replace action attribute of form.
**Note** :- you can call onclick javascript function with same code instead of biniding click event

```
$(function(){
    $("#generate").click(function(){
      var value = $('#oldCode').val();
      var div = $('<div></div>');
      $(div).append(value);

      $(div).find('form').attr('action','https://www.yyyyyyyyy.com/parse.php');

      $('#newCode').val( $(div).html());
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/90ssvnry/20/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple snippet:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var clone = $($('#oldCode').val()).clone();
    clone.attr('action', 'https://www.yyyyyyyyy.com/parse.php');
    $('#newCode').val(clone[0].outerHTML);
});
```

I.e. just create a clone of the value of the textarea, change the attribute, and add clone's HTML to the other textarea.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saxk6sc3/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to your `form` say `myForm`,

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var formClone = $('#myForm').clone();
    formClone.attr('action', 'https://www.yyyyyyyyy.com/parse.php');
    $('#newCode').text(formClone);
)};
```

Comment: The form is with in a textarea. This form should be considered as text

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` to the form.

```
<form action="https://www.xxxxxxx.com/servlet/servlet?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="form">
                                                                                     ^
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

And in the jquery function

```
$('#form').attr('action', 'https://www.yyyyyyyyy.com/parse.php '); // set the action attribute to required page
$('#newCode').html($('#form').html());   // set the html of textarea with id newCode as the html content of form with id form
```

Comment: The "form" in the question is __plain text__, not an HTML element.